# Samsung S3 I9300 - screen freezing several times

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, system-freeze

I'm a Samsung S3 user.

After I updated the OS to 4.1.2 (official release), my screen keeps on freezing. I'm fed up with those freezing situations. Any solutions for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who have  updated to 4.1.2 official release, it seems fairly likely that the release is causing the problems. If it is unreliable, you can always try rooting the phone if not already and installing a custom rom which is running on 4.1.2 rather than the official release which is clearly loaded with bugs. Alternatively, you can always flash back to your previous version .

Someone reported that disabling Samsung bloatwares cleared that issue, and also disabling wifi will decrease freezing frequency.

Look [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-siii-i9300/245894-samsung-galaxy-s3-i9300-freezes-every-hour-so.html),all are reporting same problem.

Answer (score 1):

My GS3 also started having the freezes. Started about 2 weeks ago and varied between 3-4 times a day. In the beginning I thought this was due to a recently installed app and started uninstalling all my apps one by one. When this did not help, I backed up the data and did a data wipe/factory reset from the recovery startup (Vol Up + Home + Power). This did not help either. I then googled and found out about the SDS problem, but apparently, I was covered as I had the `XELLC` build. Researching a bit more, I hit upon another solution that was suggested related to using the dummy file generator to fill up the internal SD card so that the problem which was guessed to be because of an I/O on a bad memory block would be fixed. So, here's what I did:

1. Uninstalled all the apps (did not help, problem re-occurred)
2. Did a hard reset (did not help, it froze again)
3. Used the dummy file generator (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.nomunomu.dummy&hl=en) to fill up the remaining space on my internal SD. (The phone froze during this process. I restarted and created the dummy files again, twice)
4. At this point, I did not have the freezing. I hard reset the phone again, just to be sure.
5. Next, while setting up the phone, I did not setup WiFi or add the Google account right away. I first completed the setup without adding any accounts, went to settings and turned off auto sync and then added the google account. (Something made me feel that was the problem.) I also disabled "Chat On" and "Google Chrome" that came bundled with the update.

I don't know what I did above that helped, but the freezing problem isn't there any more (as of yet). Hopefully, it doesn't return.

P.S.: I was/am running official android and updates received OTA. No root or mods.